# How to Create Project For Web Project in MS Project Online?

Tags: office365, ms-project, project-online

There is a new type of Project in Microsoft Project Online.
How to create it programmatically - from some kind of API?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backend for the new "Project For Web" is based on [Common Data Services](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/common-data-service/) so you can use Power Automate or Logic Apps Connectors.

Below you can find screenshots from the Logic Apps on portal.azure.com
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]